# Div elements are going out of manner

Tags: css, html

I am trying to keep 2 sibling div elements inside a parent div. One at left end and other at right end. But the second div element is going out of the parent div. How can I align that inside parent div?

HTML:

```
<div id="mainRect">
    <div id="topRect">
        <div id="logoRect"><img id="logo" src="images\logo.jpg" /></div>
        <div id="searchRect"><input id="searchbox" type="text" name="search"   placeholder="Search Hospital,Clinic,Doctor" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#topRect {
    width:90%;
    height:75px;
    margin:auto;
    background:#ccc2c2;
}

#logoRect {
    float:left;
    margin-left:5%;
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
}

#logo {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#searchRect {
    float:left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 25%;
    margin-left:65%;
}

#searchbox {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Online example? jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using to much margin as a result it is going out

Try to **reduce margin** like below

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b0cp6hmw/10/)**

```
#searchRect {
    float:left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 25%;
    margin-left:40%;
}
```

Or simply `float:right` and remove margin

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b0cp6hmw/11/)**

```
#searchRect {
    float:right;
    width: 30%;
    height: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `margin` property in order to position the floated elements to the sides. You could float one element to the left and the other to the right instead.

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/rakis/1/edit)**

```css
#logoRect {
    float:left;
    /* margin-left:5%; */
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
}

#searchRect {
    float:right;
    width: 30%;
    height: 25%;
    /* margin-left:65%; */
}
```

Additionally, if you want to add a space to left/right of the container (`#topRect`) you could specify a left/right padding like so:

```css
#topRect {
   padding: 0 10px;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Note:** `box-sizing: border-box` changes the calculation of width of the box so that it would include the padding and borders.

Comment: My exact thoughts (except the `margin-left`, that doesn't matter): http://jsfiddle.net/eycofo9u/

Comment: @JaredFarrish That's true. However I suggest to avoid using `margin` on the second floated element which may cause trouble if it exceeds the remained space, [something like](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/eycofo9u/1/) `margin-left:90%;`

Comment: I meant the `margin-left` on the `#logoRect`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes, that's fair.

Answer (score -1):

On the searchRect, It is either you remove the margin-left property and change the float property to right or make the margin-left property to less than or equal to 50%.